# Appending forms in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is added dynamically by pressing a button. The problem is that all process working fine the first time that i hit the button. From the 2 time, the process not working because id's of fields is the same. How i can adjust this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aggiungi_collo").click(function() {
    $('#lista_colli').append('<tr>\
      <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" class="form_control" id="cod_collo" /></td>\
      <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" class="form_control" id="larghezza" /></td>\
      <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" class="form_control" id="lunghezza" /></td>\
      <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" class="form_control" id="altezza" /></td>\
      <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" class="form_control" id="volume" /></td>\
      <td><button id="calcola" class="btn btn-primary calcola" style="background:green;border:none"><i style="color:white;height:20px" class="fa fa-trash"></i>Calcola</button></td>\
      <td><button href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="background:red;border:none"><i style="color:white;height:20px" class="fa fa-trash"></i>Elimina</a></td>\
    </tr>');

    $('#calcola').click(function() {
      var larghezza = $('#larghezza').val();
      var altezza = $('#altezza').val();
      var lunghezza = $('#lunghezza').val();
      var calcola = lunghezza * altezza * larghezza;
      var volume = document.getElementById('volume');
      volume.value = calcola;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't use ids. Use classes. `id` have to be unique. You'd also be better using a delegated event handler instead of attaching a new `click` handler each time

Comment: try creating unique `id` for dynamic HTML and use the same within `click` handler.

Comment: If, form is add dynamically, then use `.on()` method instead of `.click()`. Since on second time id's are same, please use class instead id.

Comment: Yes, use classes. Or if you really need unique identifier add some counter and add it's value to id, i.e. "calcola1", "calcola2"...and so on... So every time you add a form element you have to increase that counter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that keeps track of how many times the button has been clicked and concatenate this to your id.